# These things are what are needed

Tags: grammar

Let's say you're coaching kids about how to become the best basketball player.

Coach(you): you have to improve your dribbling, shooting, speed, and footwork, simply because these things **are** what **are** needed to become the best basketball player as you can be.

Is this grammatical? Pls. Help.

Comment: The first one needs to be "are" to match "things". The second one depends on whether you mean the concept of improvement (singular) or the skills themselves (plural).

Comment: I got what you mean, and I also thinking about that(I forgot to write those helping verbs 'is' and 'are') BUT, whether it is the 'is' or the 'are' usage, I think the meaning is still almost the same. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although technically correct, it sounds a bit awkward.  I (an American, it's likely different in the UK) would say "...because these things are needed..."  It is also common (although grammatically incorrect) to say "...because that's what's needed..."  If you're trying to stick with your original wording, you could say "...because these are the things which are needed..."  This is probably the best, but it's a bit superfluous for a kids' basketball team.

Also, say "the best basketball player you can be."  The "as" is unnecessary.